# Does an unused class constant consume memory?

Tags: php

Imagine this class with two constants

```
class Myclass
{
    const FOO = array (...) // ~50M data in here
    const BAR = array (...) // also ~50M data in here
}
```

a)

```
$foo=Myclass::FOO;
$bar=Myclass::BAR;
```

b)

```
$foo=Myclass::FOO;
```

In case a) I call both constants, which I guess will cause a memory usage about 100M. Right?

In case b) I just use one of the constants. Is the memory usage 100M anyway or just 50M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 MB. Constants are generated once per class (not class instance) at compile-time, whether you use them in subsequent code or not. This is why they must be scalar values. You can read more in the PHP manual:
[PHP - Class Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)
[PHP - Class Constant Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

Answer (score 0):

The Function bellow will return to you your memory consumption. If you pass TRUE to it, it will return the memory consumption used by the System. If you pass FALSE it will just show your memory consumption. This will help you in further tests of your question. I could not do a test now to give you an exact answer on what you need for now, but this function is very generic. And will provide more help than just in that case.

```
public static function GetMemoryUsage($System) 
{ 
        $mem_usage = memory_get_usage($System); 
        if ($mem_usage < 1024) $mem_usage = $mem_usage." B"; 
        elseif ($mem_usage < 1048576) $mem_usage = round($mem_usage/1024,2)." KB"; 
        else $mem_usage = round($mem_usage/1048576,2)." MB"; 
        return $mem_usage; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's useful